# SwiftUI - View disappears if animated

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I am building a custom segmented control. This is the code that I have written.

```
struct SegmentedControl: View {
    private var items: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    
    @Namespace var animation:Namespace.ID
    
    @State var selected: String = "One"
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.spring()){
                            self.selected = item
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text(item)
                            .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.medium))
                            .foregroundColor(selected == item ? .white : .accentColor)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                            .padding(.vertical, 10)
                            .background(zStack(item: item))
                    }
                    
                }
            } .padding()
        }
    }
    
    private func zStack(item: String) -> some View {
        ZStack{
            if selected == item {
                Color.accentColor
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Tab", in: animation)
            } else {
                Color(.gray)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
            }}
    }
}
```

**A control is Blue when it is selected.**

It works as expected most of the time like in the following GIF.

[image]

However, sometimes if you navigate back and forth very fast, the `Color.accentColor` moves off screen and disappears as you see in the following GIF. I have used a lot of time but could not fix it.

[image]

Sometimes, I get this error.

```
 Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair<String, 
    ID>(first: "Tab", second: SwiftUI.Namespace.ID(id: 248)) have `isSource: 
    true`, results are undefined.
```

---

Info, It is easier to test it on a physical device rather than a simulator.

#### Update

This is my all codde including the ContentView and the Modal.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private  var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresented.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                })
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            ModalView()
        })
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: TabbarView(),
                label: {
                   Text("Navigate")
                })
        }
    }
}


struct TabbarView: View {
    private var items: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    
    @Namespace var animation:Namespace.ID
    
    @State var selected: String = ""    // change here
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation{
                            self.selected = item
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text(item)
                            .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.medium))
                            .foregroundColor(selected == item ? .white : .accentColor)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                            .padding(.vertical, 10)
                            .background(zStack(item: item))
                    }
                    
                }
            } .padding()
        }
        .onAppear { self.selected = "One" }  // add this
    }
    
    private func zStack(item: String) -> some View {
        ZStack{
            if selected == item {
                Color.accentColor
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Tab", in: animation)
            } else {
                Color(.gray)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
            }}
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the blue button is moving off screen. Use the debugger to check its position after it disappears.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue on my device. I would suggest setting the isSource, as the error suggests. I've found that not setting this causes most of the buggy functionality with matchedGeometry.

Comment: @nicksarno If happens if you navigate back and forth very fast. Do it a few times.

Comment: Add your code for the navigating views.

Comment: @vacawama I added all of my codes.