# Using geometry effect results in "Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair" warnings

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I use matched geometry view modifier I sometimes get the following warning multiple times with different values for 'first':

```
Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair<Int, ID>(first: 42, second: SwiftUI.Namespace.ID(id: 84)) have `isSource: true`, results are undefined.
```

The error appears after I click the 'newGame' button (for exactly three times in a row) or tap on the 'cardDeck' (after I have clicked on 'newGame' for exactly two times). While the animation stills works (see GIF below), I'd like to understand why I get this warning and how can I fix the problem.

[image: Snippet of app in use]

Please find the corresponding code below.

Thank you very much for your help!

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var viewModel = ShapeSetGame()

   @Namespace private var dealingNamespace

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           gameBody
           Spacer()
           HStack {
               cardDeck
               Spacer()
               newGame
               Spacer()
               discardPile
           }
           .padding(3)
       }
   }

   var gameBody: some View {
       AspectVGrid(items: viewModel.cardsInGame, aspectRatio: CardConstants.aspectRatio) { card in
           CardView(
               amount: card.content.amount.rawValue,
               type: card.content.type.rawValue,
               color: card.content.color.rawValue,
               shading: card.content.shading.rawValue,
               selected: viewModel.selectedCards.contains(card),
               mismatch: viewModel.mismatchCards.contains(card),
               matched: card.isMatched,
               faceUp: true
           )
           .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace)
           .zIndex(zIndex(of: card))
           .padding(3)
           .onTapGesture {
               withAnimation {
                   viewModel.choose(card)
               }
           }
       }
   }

   var cardDeck: some View {
       ZStack {
           ForEach(viewModel.cardDeck) { card in
               CardView(
                   amount: card.content.amount.rawValue,
                   type: card.content.type.rawValue,
                   color: card.content.color.rawValue,
                   shading: card.content.shading.rawValue,
                   selected: viewModel.selectedCards.contains(card),
                   mismatch: viewModel.mismatchCards.contains(card),
                   matched: card.isMatched,
                   faceUp: false
               )
               .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace)
               .zIndex(zIndex(of: card))
           }
       }
       .frame(width: CardConstants.undealtWidth, height: CardConstants.undealtHeight)
       .onTapGesture {
           withAnimation {
               viewModel.deal()
           }
       }
       .disabled(viewModel.cardDeckComplete)
   }

   var discardPile: some View {
       ZStack {
           ForEach(viewModel.discardedCards) { card in
               CardView(
                   amount: card.content.amount.rawValue,
                   type: card.content.type.rawValue,
                   color: card.content.color.rawValue,
                   shading: card.content.shading.rawValue,
                   selected: viewModel.selectedCards.contains(card),
                   mismatch: viewModel.mismatchCards.contains(card),
                   matched: card.isMatched,
                   faceUp: true
               )
               .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace)
           }
       }
       .frame(width: CardConstants.undealtWidth, height: CardConstants.undealtHeight)
   }

   var newGame: some View {
       Button(action: {
           withAnimation {
               viewModel.new()
           }
        
       }, label: {
           Text("New Game")
       })
       .padding()
       .foregroundColor(.white)
       .background(.gray)
   }

   private func zIndex(of card: ShapeSetGame.ShapeSetCard) -> Double {
       -Double(viewModel.cardDeck.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) ?? 0)
   }

   private struct CardConstants {
       static let aspectRatio: CGFloat = 2/3
       static let undealtHeight: CGFloat = 90
       static let undealtWidth: CGFloat = undealtHeight * aspectRatio
       static let dealDuration: Double = 0.5
       static let totalDealDuration: Double = 2
   }
```

}

ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI

class ShapeSetGame: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = SetGame<ShapeAmount, ShapeType, ShapeColor, ShapeShading>()

    typealias ShapeSetCard = Card<ShapeAmount, ShapeType, ShapeColor, ShapeShading>

    var cardsInGame: Array<ShapeSetCard> {
        return model.cardsInGame
    }

    var discardedCards: Array<ShapeSetCard> {
        return model.discardedCards
    }

    var cardDeck: Array<ShapeSetCard> {
        return model.cardDeck
    }

    var selectedCards: Array<ShapeSetCard> {
        return model.selectedCards
    }

    var mismatchCards: Array<ShapeSetCard> {
        return model.mismatchCards
    }

    var cardDeckComplete: Bool {
        return model.cardsInGame.count == 0 && model.discardedCards.count == 0
    }

    var cardDeckIsEmpty: Bool {
        return model.cardDeck.count == 0
    }

    enum ShapeAmount: Int {
        case one = 1, two = 2, three = 3
    }

    enum ShapeType: String {
        case oval, diamond, squiggle
    }

    enum ShapeColor: String {
        case red, blue, green
    }

    enum ShapeShading: String {
        case solid, striped, outlined
    }

    // MARK: - Intent(s)
    func deal() {
        model.dealThreeCards()
    }

    func new() {
        model.newGame()
    }

    func choose(_ card: ShapeSetCard) {
        model.choose(card)
    }
}

extension ShapeSetGame.ShapeAmount: CaseIterable {

}

extension ShapeSetGame.ShapeType: CaseIterable {

}

extension ShapeSetGame.ShapeColor: CaseIterable {

}

extension ShapeSetGame.ShapeShading: CaseIterable {

}
```

Model:

```
import Foundation

struct SetGame<Feature1, Feature2, Feature3, Feature4> where Feature1: CaseIterable, Feature1: Equatable, Feature2: CaseIterable, Feature2: Equatable, Feature3: CaseIterable, Feature3: Equatable, Feature4: CaseIterable, Feature4: Equatable {

   typealias SetCard = Card<Feature1, Feature2, Feature3, Feature4>
   private(set) var cardDeck: Array<SetCard> = []
   var cardsInGame: Array<SetCard> = []
   private let startNumberOfCardsInGame = 12
   var selectedCards: Array<SetCard> = []
   var mismatchCards: Array<SetCard> = []
   var discardedCards: Array<SetCard> = []

   mutating func newGame() {
       cardDeck = []
       cardsInGame = []
       selectedCards = []
       mismatchCards = []
       discardedCards = []
       startGame()
       for _ in 0..<startNumberOfCardsInGame {
           cardsInGame.append(cardDeck[0])
           cardDeck.remove(at: 0)
       }
   }

   mutating func dealThreeCards() {
       let matchedCardsInGame = cardsInGame.filter { $0.isMatched }
       if matchedCardsInGame.count == 3 {
           exchangeCards()
       } else {
           if cardDeck.count > 0 {
               for _ in 0..<3 {
                   cardsInGame.append(cardDeck[0])
                   cardDeck.remove(at: 0)
               }
           }
       }
       for card in cardDeck {
           print (card.id)
       }
   }

   mutating func choose(_ card: SetCard) {
       mismatchCards = []
       removeCards()
       let cardsInGame = cardsInGame.filter { $0.isMatched == false }
       if let chosenIndex = cardsInGame.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) {
           if selectedCards.contains(card) {
               if let selectedIndex = selectedCards.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) {
                   selectedCards.remove(at: selectedIndex)
               }
          } else {
               if selectedCards.count == 2 {
                   checkForMatch(card1: selectedCards[0], card2: selectedCards[1], card3: card)
               } else {
                   selectedCards.append(cardsInGame[chosenIndex])
               }
           }
       }
   }

   init() {
       startGame()
   }

   //MARK: - Helper functions
   private mutating func startGame() {
       var identifier = 0
       for f1 in Feature1.allCases {
           for f2 in Feature2.allCases {
               for f3 in Feature3.allCases {
                   for f4 in Feature4.allCases {
                       let card = SetCard(content: SetCard.Content(amount: f1, type: f2, color: f3, shading: f4), id: identifier)
                       cardDeck.append(card)
                       identifier += 1
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       cardDeck.shuffle()
   }

   private mutating func checkForMatch(card1: SetCard, card2: SetCard, card3: SetCard) {
       if ((card1.content.amount != card2.content.amount) && (card1.content.amount != card3.content.amount) && (card2.content.amount != card3.content.amount)) || ((card1.content.amount == card2.content.amount) && (card1.content.amount == card3.content.amount) && (card2.content.amount == card3.content.amount)) {
               if ((card1.content.type != card2.content.type) && (card1.content.type != card3.content.type) && (card2.content.type != card3.content.type)) || ((card1.content.type == card2.content.type) && (card1.content.type == card3.content.type) && (card2.content.type == card3.content.type)) {
                       if ((card1.content.color != card2.content.color) && (card1.content.color != card3.content.color) && (card2.content.color != card3.content.color)) || ((card1.content.color == card2.content.color) && (card1.content.color == card3.content.color) && (card2.content.color == card3.content.color)) {
                               if (card1.content.shading != card2.content.shading) && (card1.content.shading != card3.content.shading) && (card2.content.shading != card3.content.shading) || ((card1.content.shading == card2.content.shading) && (card1.content.shading == card3.content.shading) && (card2.content.shading == card3.content.shading)) {
                                       if let chosenIndex1 = cardsInGame.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card1.id }), let chosenIndex2 = cardsInGame.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card2.id }), let chosenIndex3 = cardsInGame.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card3.id }) {
                                           cardsInGame[chosenIndex1].isMatched = true
                                           cardsInGame[chosenIndex2].isMatched = true
                                           cardsInGame[chosenIndex3].isMatched = true
                                           selectedCards = []
                                       }
                               } else {
                                   addMismatchCards(card1: card1, card2: card2, card3: card3)
                               }
                        } else {
                          addMismatchCards(card1: card1, card2: card2, card3: card3)
                       }
               } else {
                   addMismatchCards(card1: card1, card2: card2, card3: card3)
               }
       } else {
           addMismatchCards(card1: card1, card2: card2, card3: card3)
       }
   }

   private mutating func addMismatchCards(card1: SetCard, card2: SetCard, card3: SetCard) {
       mismatchCards.append(card1)
       mismatchCards.append(card2)
       mismatchCards.append(card3)
       selectedCards = []
   }

   private mutating func exchangeCards() {
       for card in cardsInGame {
           if card.isMatched == true {
               if let selectedIndex = cardsInGame.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) {
                   if cardDeck.count > 0 {
                       discardedCards.append(card)
                       cardsInGame[selectedIndex] = cardDeck[0]
                       cardDeck.remove(at: 0)
                   } else {
                       discardedCards.append(card)
                       cardsInGame.remove(at: selectedIndex)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }

   private mutating func removeCards() {
       for card in cardsInGame {
           if card.isMatched == true {
               if let selectedIndex = cardsInGame.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) {
                   discardedCards.append(card)
                   cardsInGame.remove(at: selectedIndex)
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly use matchedGeometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64581837/how-to-properly-use-matchedgeometry)

Comment: Had a look at this thread but honestly don't understand how to apply this explanation to my specific problem.

Comment: The root of the issue appears to be that you don't clear the last set of cards before you reset them. You haven't shown enough code to figure out where you are doing(not doing?) it, but the error message is pretty clear. But, as you said yourself, it won't appear unless you click "New Game". Somewhere there, you have to clear the views, before resetting the game.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment - I have added the model of my app as I believe I correctly reset the last set of cards (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: We would need to see `ShapeSetGame` as that is what actually updates the view. Your scenario really exists in `ContentView()` You show the first set of matched geo cards. You then restart the game. Sometimes, the old cards aren't cleared before the new cards show. That showing is triggered from the update in `ShapeSetGame`. You may even just need to wait a cycle before the new cards are shown with a simple `Dispatchqueue.main.async` to get the timing right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have added ShapeSetGame (the ViewModel).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245002/discussion-between-yrb-and-sebastian).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turns out the problem is you have to "remove" the view you are trying to replace. Since I am using a `LazyVGrid` I didn't want to remove the view itself since it would change the layout and cause conflicting animations. Instead I "replace" the view with a placeholder view that does NOT have the `.matchedGeometryEffect(...)` modifier when expanding a card view.

Here is my working example:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(Array(cardViewModels.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, cardViewModel in
        let isExpanded = selectedIndex == index
        if isExpanded { // Need to create a new placeholder view without the `.matchedGeometryEffect(...)` modifier to prevent duplicate sources error.
            Color.clear
                .frame(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight, alignment: .top)
        } else {
            Image("snapshot")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .transition(.scale(scale: 1.0))
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: cardViewModel.id, in: animation)
                .transition(.scale(scale: 1.0))
                .frame(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight, alignment: .top)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        selectedIndex = index
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
.overlay {
    // Show expanded view as an overlay on the LazyVGrid...
    if let selectedIndex,
       let cardViewModel = cardViewModels[selectedIndex] {
        Image("snapshot")
            .resizable()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: cardViewModel.id, in: animation)
            .transition(.scale(scale: 1.0))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .scaledToFill()
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    lastSelectedIndex = selectedIndex
                    selectedIndex = nil
                }
            }
    }
}
```